# Filter XML file with xpath using python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm trying to grab some data from a XML file that I generated after I did a network scan in my test environment. The XML file that I got back gave me an enormous amount of information which I want to filter.

The only systems I'm interested in are the systems with the state "up"

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
mydoc = ElementTree(file='nmap_output.xml')
for e in mydoc.findall("./nmaprun/host/state[@state='up']"):
print (e.get('title').text )
```

Below I posted a part of the XML file that I'm using, it's far too large to post it entirely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 7.40 scan initiated Mon Jul 10 18:24:16 2017 as: nmap -sS -O -vv -oX c:\\drv\\1921689024.xml 192.168.9.0/24 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -sS -O -vv -oX c:\\drv\\1921689024.xml 192.168.9.0/24" start="1499703856" startstr="Mon Jul 10 18:24:16 2017" version="7.40" xmloutputversion="1.04">
<taskbegin task="Ping Scan" time="1499703857"/>
<taskend task="Ping Scan" time="1499703860" extrainfo="256 total hosts"/>
<taskbegin task="Parallel DNS resolution of 256 hosts." time="1499703860"/>
<taskend task="Parallel DNS resolution of 256 hosts." time="1499703860"/>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.0" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.2" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.3" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.4" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.6" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.9" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host><status state="down" reason="no-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.10" addrtype="ipv4"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1499703857" endtime="1499704025"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="249"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="man-nas-01.man.eu.cascorp.biz" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="991">
<extrareasons reason="resets" count="991"/>
</extraports>
</host>
<host starttime="1499703857" endtime="1499704025"><status state="up" 
reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="249"/>
<address addr="192.168.9.7" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
</nmaprun>
```

Could anyone help me show how I can get only the hosts with the state "up"?

Answer (score 0):

This finds all `<host>` tags which have a `<status state="up">` child.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('nmap_output.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.findall(".//status[@state='up']/.."))
```

(found examples on [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example))

Comment: Yes I also found this one on the python docs, but when I run it I only get a blanc output. I don't get any error, just nothing.

[screenshot](http://i66.tinypic.com/j5woi0.png)

Comment: @killerdoomc of course, it doesn't print anything :) Edited.

Comment: Oh of course, I did not realise that the print was missing, stupid of me!

My current output is  
    "[<Element 'host' at 0x0000023600602CC8>, <Element 'host' at 
    0x000002360060DD18>, <Element 'host' at 0x0000023600617818>,"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to get the hosts with the following xpath

```
mydoc.findall('.//host/status[@state="up"]/..')
```

If you want to get the addresses you could use

```
addresses = mydoc.findall('.//host/status[@state="up"]/../address')

for address in addresses:
    print(address.get('addr'))
```

Comment: When I run 
mydoc.findall('.//host/status[@state="up"]/..')

It gives me a NoneType error, also when I add /nmaprun/ before host I only get a blanc answer. No error, just nothing.

Comment: That's strange. I got it working in the console using the xml sample you provided and Python 3.6. Did you use `'.//host/status[@state="up"]/..'` or `'.//host/state[@state="up"]/..'`? I notice in your question above you used the latter.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... how I can get only the hosts with the state "up"?

---

> **Note**: Your Example XML is invalid for the following Reasons:
>
> Additonal `<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>` could be only **one**!
>   Missing closing `</ports>`
>   Missing closing `</host>`

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

mydoc = ElementTree(file='nmap_output.xml')

# Find all <host> Elements with <status state="up" ...>
for host in mydoc.findall('.//host/status[@state="up"]/..'):

    # Get the Attributes Dict from <host> <status ...> and <address ...>
    status = host.find('.//status').attrib
    address = host.find('.//address').attrib

    print ('host: addr={a[addr]}, status: {s[state]} reason={s[reason]}'.
             format(a=address, s=status))
```

> **Qutput**:
>
> ```
> host: addr=192.168.9.1, status: up reason=echo-reply
> host: addr=192.168.9.7, status: up reason=echo-reply
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked and the format is nice. It could indeed be that I missed 1 or 2 closing, because I removed the sensitive information from the XML.

Comment: @killerdoomc: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)